# How to alter login logic if I add admin privileges in windows form?

Tags: c#

Currently, I have a name and password column in my table. However, I want to add a "UserRights" column, with admin and user rights. If an admin logs in, he should see a different form compared to the user.

Currently, I have an `if` statement to check if the login details are right. If yes, it goes to a home winform. Else, there is an error message to check details. However, if I had this new column, there would be two checks one for details and one for user rights and then the error if details do not match, how could this be done?

```
private void check_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(@"");
    string query = "select * from dbo.users where name= '" + name.Text+ "' and password = '" + dbo.users where pword= '" + pword.Text+ "'";
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlcon);
    DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dtbl);
    if (dtbl.Rows.Count == 1)
    ...
}
```

Comment: This `sda.Fill(dtbl)` already gives you all columns from `users`.  So just check the columns in `dtbl`.  Also, obligatory comment that you have a possible SQL injection attack due to not using parameterized queries.  And passwords should never be stored as plain text.

Comment: Once you get user roles for the authorized user, either use a `switch` statement or an `if-else` statement and hand them different views. 1 role should have the same logic as 1+n roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your *userrights* column to your select query and then add an additional check for their privileges.

It should look similar to this

```
            SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(@"");
            string query = "select * from dbo.users where name= '" + name.Text+ "' and password = '" + dbo.users where pword= '" + pword.Text+ "'";
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlcon);
            DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dtbl);
            if (dtbl.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
               string userRights = dtbl.Rows[0]["userrights"].ToType<string>();
               switch (userRights)
               {
                  case "admin":
                     *do something*
                  break;
                  case "user":
                     *do something else*
                  break;
               }
            }
```